# Create a list of multiple identical (same dimension) matrices in R

Tags: r, list, matrix, paste, dimensions

I am creating *N* number of **matrices** (*M1, M2, ... Mn*) of the same size (*C x R*) and store them in the **list** *L*.

My code is the following:

```
C=2 #columns
R=3 #rows
N=6 #number of matrices
M1 <- matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C)))
M2 <- matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C)))
M3 <- matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C)))
M4 <- matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C)))
M5 <- matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C)))
M6 <- matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C)))
L <- mget(paste0("M", 1:N)) #list of matrices
L
```

The results look like this:

```
$M1
        Player 1 Player 2
Round 1        0        0
Round 2        0        0
Round 3        0        0

$M2
        Player 1 Player 2
Round 1        0        0
Round 2        0        0
Round 3        0        0

$M3
        Player 1 Player 2
Round 1        0        0
Round 2        0        0
Round 3        0        0

$M4
        Player 1 Player 2
Round 1        0        0
Round 2        0        0
Round 3        0        0

$M5
        Player 1 Player 2
Round 1        0        0
Round 2        0        0
Round 3        0        0

$M6
        Player 1 Player 2
Round 1        0        0
Round 2        0        0
Round 3        0        0
```

Is there a more efficient way to build such a list **L**?

Comment: Yep, you can use `replicate`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about:

```
L <- replicate(10, matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C))), simplify=FALSE)
names(L) <- paste0("M", 1:10)
```

### edit

use `setNames` as @akrun did, to simplify further

```
setNames(replicate(10, matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),paste("Player", 1:C))), simplify=FALSE), 
paste0("M", 1:10))
```

Comment: these are excellent answers! Although all three codes including @akrun 's one do the job perfectly, your last modification is the most intuitive.

Answer (score 2):

Try using `lapply`

```
 setNames(lapply(1:6, function(i) 
       matrix(0, ncol=C, nrow=R, dimnames=list(paste("Round",1:R),
                         paste("Player", 1:C)))), paste0("M", 1:6))
```